# How to implement an interface in MainActivity by calling the method in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, interface

I have to implement an interface in the MainActivity which is defined in a custom adapter. But all the related objects of that interface methods are defined in the fragment. So how do I communicate between the MainActivity and the fragment in order to make the implementation of the interface work without getting a null pointer exception?

This is the interface that I have to implement which is defined in a custom adapter.

```
public interface UpdateMainClass{
        void updateItemList(int position);
        void updateListBackground(int position, boolean isChecked);
    }
```

In my Main Activity I override the above.

```
/**
     * <p>This method is used to remove the item from speicified position</p>
     * @param position location of the item to be removed
     */
    @Override
    public void updateItemList(int position) {
        myNewFragment.updateItemList(position);
    }

    /**
     * <p>Updates the background checkbox status in POJO class and helps to set the background color on long press.</p>
     * <p>Illegal state is checked to prevent changing of checkbox status while list is being scrolled.</p>
     * @param position position of the item in list where checkbox status is changed.
     * @param isChecked current status of the checkbox.
     */
    @Override
    public void updateListBackground(int position, boolean isChecked) {
        myNewFragment.updateListBackground(position, isChecked);
    }
```

This is my Fragment class where I can actually implement the method.

```
/**
     * <p>This method is used to remove the item from speicified position</p>
     *
     * @param position location of the item to be removed
     */
    public void updateItemList(int position) {
        myArrayList.remove(position);
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    /**
     * <p>Updates the background checkbox status in POJO class and helps to set the background color on long press.</p>
     * <p>Illegal state is checked to prevent changing of checkbox status while list is being scrolled.</p>
     *
     * @param position  position of the item in list where checkbox status is changed.
     * @param isChecked current status of the checkbox.
     */
    public void updateListBackground(int position, boolean isChecked) {
        try {
            if (isChecked)
                myArrayList.get(position).setCompleted(1);
            else
                myArrayList.get(position).setCompleted(0);
            mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
```

This Obviously does not work and I end up getting a null pointer exception at `myArrayList.get(position)` in my fragment class. So is there a better way to code this?

Comment: you want access activity method from fragment  ??

Comment: It's actually the other way around

Answer (score 0):

It won't happen that way.

First, you create an interface which has the methods which will use to communicate between your fragment and host activity.

Second, you implement that interface in your host activity and do your business logic.

Third, you get a callback of your activity in the fragment's onAttach() method:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
   super.onAttach(activity);

   try {
     callback = (UpdateMainClass) activity;
   } catch (ClassCastException e) {
     throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
            + " must implement UpdateMainClass");
   }
}
```

Forth, you call these interface methods from your fragment via activity's callback field like:

```
callback.updateItemList(_data_);
```

And this is [Fragment -> Activity communication](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity).

If you want to access fragment's methods from the host activity, you should get reference of your fragment from the FragmentManager.

The best solution will be usage of EventBus libs like Otto, EventBus or RxBus.

Comment: The Interface UpdateMainClass is not defined in the fragment but in a custom adapter.

Comment: Okay, then the way you have to communicate with your Fragment will be: Adapter -> Activity -> Fragment. 

Better way is to research the event bus libraries I mentioned above. They will save you a lot of time!